# How do you get the attributes and flags used on CreateFile?

Tags: windows, winapi, storage

If I have a `HANDLE` and want to get the various attributes and flags used on the `CreateFile` or `OpenFile` to open or create the file, how is that done?

TIA!!

Comment: use the [`NtQueryInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile). say *FileModeInformation* - return [`FILE_MODE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_mode_information) where you can check for `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` and `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` flags. so are file handle for synchronous file object or no. but all this is XY problem for you.

Comment: actually that doesn't seem to work from user mode anyway.  Always getting back Mode of `0x00000008` when the device was opened with `0x40000000`

Comment: this is of course work from user mode. 8 this is `FILE_NO_INTERMEDIATE_BUFFERING` . the `0x40000000` (i understand that you mean `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`) here unrelated. you see - `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT` or `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` flags ? no. so if you use `CreateFile` - this mean that `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` is set. also `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` was set, if you not mistake with post result here. if api "not work" - it return error status.

Comment: The `FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_ALERT` is 0x10, I checked the CreateFile and it only opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED.

Comment: in `FILE_MODE_INFORMATION.Mode` was flag used in call NtCreateFile/NtOpenFile. are you inderstand this ? are you understand that `CreateFile` used absolute another flags ?

Comment: But the question was how to determine if the handle created with `CreateFile` (or `OpenFile`) was opened (overlapped or not).

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying now.